# Where should an /opt package write logs?

Tags: logs, fhs

I am installing a custom package to `/opt/package_name`, storing configuration files in `/etc/opt/package_name` and static files in `/var/opt/package_name/static/` - all following the conventions suggested by FHS. [[1](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES)] [[2](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#ETCOPTCONFIGURATIONFILESFOROPT)] [[3](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VAROPTVARIABLEDATAFOROPT)]

I also need to store some logfiles. I want them to be discoverable by analysis tools, so they should also be in a conventional location. Should these go in:

- `/var/log/package_name` (like a system package, even though this is a custom package)
- `/var/opt/package_name/log` (following the `/var/opt` convention - but is this discoverable?)
- something else?

Comment: Do you have an example of an analysis tool in mind which scans /var/log?

Comment: Why isn't the answer syslog?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would place them in `/var/log/package_name`; it satisfies the principle of least surprise better than `/var/opt/package_name/log`. I don't have a citation for this; it simply matches where I'd look for logs.

I might also forego writing my own log files, and instead log to `syslog` with an appropriate tag and facility; if I'm looking for clean integration with established analysis tools, I don't believe I can do better for a communications channel:

- Every generic tool with "log analysis" as a listed feature already watches `syslog`.
- Log file release and rotation semantics are handled for me; I don't have to set up a mechanism for `logrotate` to tell me to let go of the file and open a new one. I don't even have to tell `logrotate` about new files to rotate!
- Offloading logs to central logging servers is handled for me, if the site demands it; Existing established tools like `rsyslog` will be in use if needed, so I don't have to contemplate implementing that feature myself.
- Access controls (POSIX and, e.g. SELinux) around the log files are already handled, so I don't need to pay as much attention to distribution-specific security semantics.

Unless I'm doing some custom binary format for my log and even then, I prefer syslog-friendly machine-parseable text formats like JSON. I have a hard time justifying my own separate log files; analysis tools already watch `syslog` like a hawk.

Answer (score 8):

As you are following the FHS conventions for your package configuration files, you should be consistent and store the log files in `/var/opt/package_name/log`.

The FHS states:

> [Variable data of the packages in /opt **must be installed** in /var/opt/](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s12.html)

and also states

> [**No other package files may exist outside the /opt, /var/opt, and /etc/opt hierarchies** except for those package files that must reside in specific locations within the filesystem tree in order to function properly. For example, device lock files must be placed in /var/lock and devices must be located in /dev.](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s13.html)

Having the log files under `/var/opt` doesn't prevent the package to function properly so using `/var/log` instead clearly violates the standard.

It is unclear what you mean by "is this discoverable?" as you custom logs are likely to be handled by custom tools anyway but assuming a generic tool is designed to process them, it should explore the standard location for unbundled packages like yours.

Note that `syslog` is a useful facility to centralize and tune the logging configuration but doesn't fully solve the issue about where to store logs when you have to do it in plain files with a well known path. Some files sometimes stored in an application log directory are designed to be accessible using their expected path by the application itself or by associated programs, for example a file storing a process ID, so `syslog` won't work for them.